# Color setting works for only for "HELP" tab in man page, dosen't work for the entire man page

Tags: pager, manpage

I'm trying to colorize the manual page for better visaul effect, but the setting(export some env variable in `.bashrc`) fails to work for man page, and it only work when I push `h` to get `SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS`

I put these setting in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;38;5;74m'  # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'           # end mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'           # end standout-mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[38;5;246m'    # begin standout-mode - info box
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'           # end underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[04;38;5;146m' # begin underline
export PAGER='less'
```

And in `/etc/man_db.conf`, the default setting for man is:

```
#DEFINE     pager   less -s                                                     
#DEFINE     cat cat                                                             
#DEFINE     tr  tr '\255\267\264\327' '\055\157\047\170'                        
#DEFINE     grep    grep                                                        
#DEFINE     troff   groff -mandoc                                               
#DEFINE     nroff   nroff -mandoc
```

It seems that `man` dosen't generate termcap control sequence correctly when invoking `troff`. ( or `groff`, `nroff`? I'm not sure ) Thus the `less` pager can't generate the color escape sequence.
Did I get anything wrong? Or is there something I can try to fix this problem?

terminal emultator: xterm
operating system: Fedora 22

(The vocabulary may be odd, English is not my native language, sorry for that)

Here are the screenshot showing this weird situation:
(I can not include image due to low reputation.)
[man: no color rendered](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833397/WebImage/StackOverflow/Screenshot%202015-09-04%2003.39.48.png)
[help tab in man: color rendered](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833397/WebImage/StackOverflow/Screenshot%202015-09-04%2003.39.57.png)

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Try the solution you can find at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119/30499

Comment: Thanks for you response, but the two solution dosen't works for me. Using `most` as pager does work, but I still prefer to use `less` because the consistent UX with `vim`.

Comment: Which terminal emulator and which operating system are you using?

Comment: Xterm, and I'm running Fedora 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed Fedora 22, reproduced your problem and managed to solve it with the following command:

```
export GROFF_NO_SGR=1
```

I found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/colored-man-pages-not-working-on-gentoo

Comment: It realy works!! Thanks!!  
So this problem is indeed caused by some config issue of roff engine.

Comment: Wow. I am using manjaro linux and this fixed colors for man pages when using most. Thank you!